# Working remotely for a Japanese company as a non-resident outside Japan

Tags: income-tax, india, foreign-income, dtaa, japan

As the title suggests, I am currently performing remote work as an intern for a Japanese company. I am non-Japanese nationality residing outside of Japan.

Am I subject to the flat [non-resident tax of 20.42%](https://taxsummaries.pwc.com/japan/individual/taxes-on-personal-income#:%7E:text=Non-residents,x%20102.1%25%20%3D%2020.42%25)  ?

Would I then also have to pay income tax at my own country (India) as well ?